# Loop through json and display in a table

Tags: php, json, loops

I have this json which I would like to display in an html table but I can't figure out how to accomplish it.

```
{
```

"CPPG-AETOPTII-N1": {
    "11044": "359.47",
    "11045": "47.49",
    "description": "Aetna - HMO/PPO - Option II"
  },
  "CPPG-HMODALP-21": {
    "description": "BCBS - HMO (Dallas-PCP-POS 21)",
    "0001F": "0.00",
    "0001M": "7.63",
    "0001U": "5.00"
  },
  "CPPG-HMODALP-22": {
    "description": "BCBS - HMO (Dallas-PCP-POS 22)",
    "0401T": "40.75"
  }
}

Using PHP I would like to display the json in a table like this:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>blank space</td>
<td>Aetna - HMO\/PPO - Option II</td><td>BCBS - HMO (Dallas-PCP-POS 21)</td><td>BCBS - HMO (Dallas-PCP-POS 22)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11044</td>
<td>359.47</td><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11045</td>
<td>47.49</td><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0001F</td>
<td></td><td>0.00</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0001M</td>
<td></td><td>7.63</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0001U</td>
<td></td><td>5.00</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0401T</td>
<td></td><td></td>
<td>40.75</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0402T</td>
<td></td><td></td>
<td>2500.00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your data looks like JSON, not a PHP array. Can you post the relevant output for the PHP array instead, or format the JSON to be more readable.

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. Then iterate over the array

Comment: {
  "CPPG-AETOPTII-N1": {
    "11044": "359.47",
    "11045": "47.49",
    "description": "Aetna - HMO/PPO - Option II"
  },
  "CPPG-HMODALP-21": {
    "description": "BCBS - HMO (Dallas-PCP-POS 21)",
    "0001F": "0.00",
    "0001M": "7.63",
    "0001U": "5.00"
  },
  "CPPG-HMODALP-22": {
    "description": "BCBS - HMO (Dallas-PCP-POS 22)",
    "0401T": "40.75"
  }
}

Comment: It is json. My bad. I pasted the formatted version for user friendly reading but stackoverflow doesn't keep the format. See above.

Answer (score 0):

json_decode function with assoc set true (convert object to array) will solve your problem

Usage:

`json_decode($json, true);`

Code for you case:
https://pastebin.com/dVbpj6sS

Comment: Your solution almost worked. Your solution only populated 2 columns but it didnt populate the header row with the "description". And I also need each description to fall under its own column. See my example from my original question (sample html table)

Comment: You have the solution now, I don't think you want someone else to code everything for you ?